# SQL query in Grafana is not showing results in graph

Tags: sql-server, graph, grafana

My Grafana is connected to a SQL Server datasource. I have written a simple query that extracts data values between 2 dates:

`SELECT * FROM dbo.StockQuote WHERE TransferAc = '225130' AND createDate BETWEEN '2008-02-18T01:09:12Z' AND '2020-04-01T02:09:12Z' ORDER BY 1;`

I wish to view the results in the form of a graph. My host OS is Windows so I was hoping Unixtime is not required. Even after following official documentation from Grafana and even after searching for similar questions on the web, I am kinda stuck.

Any leads or sample query would be highly appreciated. What's wrong with my query? What am I missing?

Comment: Can you be clearer in your question. What type of graph are you trying to plot? Have you tried viewing the result of the query in a table to check that you are getting the right values? To do this, at the bottom of the query by `Format as` select `Table`, then in `Visualization` select `Table`. In addition, use `Query Inspector` at the top right to see if  there are an error messages.

Comment: @Chod, I am trying to plot a graph showing entries that were created between Feb.18, 2008 and April 1, 2020. So, I expect to see, dates or timeperiod on X-Axis and number of values created on Y-Axis. Yes I can view result of query in a table form. I can confirm there are no error messages within Query Inspector.

Comment: @Chod, In order to test, I made a new simple query this time "Use StockQuote
Select * from dbo.dow_jones_index Where stock = 'AA' Order By 1".  I can see query result in table form but I don't see  'Visualization' feature in same query window within Grafana. What I did in Grafana was, choose Explore from left side, add query, choose Format As 'Table' and 'Run Query' in top right corner. If I choose 'Format As Timeseries' I see error 'Found no column named time'. Any pointers in right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks. Screenshots: https://prnt.sc/rueeq0 and https://prnt.sc/ruef1p

Comment: Interesting, what version of Grafana are you using? So how about you try the query: `SELECT date as time, avg(open) as open FROM dbo.dow_jones_index WHERE stock = 'AA' GROUP BY time, ORDER BY time;` - should plot the average value for open over time. I haven't used MySQL Server as a data source with Grafana, so could you also show what information comes up when you click `Show Help`, as this will help with your problem.